# Unaligned page numbers with titletoc with different text formatting for sections

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, titletoc

When using the `\titlecontents` command of titletoc to create different text formats for the different section levels, the page numbers become unaligned. For example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsmargin{2.55em}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\scshape}{\thecontentslabel}{}{\hfill \contentspage[\bfseries \thecontentspage]}
\titlecontents{section}[2cm]{\bfseries}{\thecontentslabel}{}{\hfill \contentspage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\chapter{Lorem}
\section{Ipsum}
\end{document}
```

Results in (red line added by me for demonstration) [image: unaligned page numbers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The problem seems to be specifically with using formatting commands such as `\bfseries` in the before/above part of the command. Somehow they end up influencing how the filler part works. One solution I found was using `\normalfont` first thing in the filler part and reapplying any formatting to the page number afterwards (if desired). Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsmargin{2.55em}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\scshape}{\thecontentslabel}{}{\normalfont\hfill \contentspage[\bfseries \thecontentspage]}
\titlecontents{section}[2cm]{\bfseries}{\thecontentslabel}{}{\normalfont\hfill \contentspage[\bfseries \thecontentspage]}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\chapter{Lorem}
\section{Ipsum}
\end{document}
```

This now results in [image]
However it should be noted that `\contentsmargin` seems to also play some part here, since I needed to add it to the first example in order to get at least strongly noticeable misalignment. I very much welcome thoughts and explainations from the experts why that is.

Answer (score 1):

`\contentsmargin` is for the *right* margin of the table of contents. This code produces a right margin of 1cm:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
 \usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsmargin{1cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[3em]{\scshape}{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.8em}}{}{\hfill\bfseries\thecontentspage}
\titlecontents{section}[2cm]{\bfseries}{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\dimexpr2cm-2.6em}}{}{\hfill\thecontentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem}

\section{Ipsum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing to `\contentsmargin{0cm}` gives:

[image]

Comment: Yes I'm aware however how and why does that affect the alignment? try it yourself, remove the contentsmargin from the code in my "question" and it's pretty much aligned. I just did a bit more experimentation and for `\contentsmargin{0em}` alignment is also achieved. But already for a value of 2pc misalignment can be detected by drawing a line. It is very miniscule though. At 1em it is noticeable to the naked eye.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. It only seems to occur if you change the font in `\titlecontents` **and** specify `\contentsmargin` in em units. Since the size of 1em depends on the font size, titletoc puts the page number in an incorrectly sized box.
The easiest solution is to specify `\contentsmargin` in another unit, say

```
\contentsmargin{30pt}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you saw the answer of user @bernhard?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it doesn't actually address the original question. My answer is actually a response to @Danieru's answer above, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.