# alignment problems for \part and \chapter in table of contents created with titletoc

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, page-numbering, titletoc

In my table of contents, created using titletoc, there are some alignment problems that I am unable to debug.

**Problem 1:**
My code allows me to control the label width for chapters and sections, but not for parts: there the label width seems to depend on the letter used as part label (I need to use customized part labels, involving letters that correlate with the part titles), with `W` producing a much wider label width than `I`. This results in part titles that are not aligned with the chapter titles.

**Problem 2:** 
The page numbers on the right are not well aligned -- this is glaringly clear for part page numbers larger than 100, but actually also true for boldface chapter numbers versus unboldface section numbers. I need to use `\large` boldface fonts for part, and normalsize boldface fonts for chapters.

Help would be much appreciated! I have spent hours customizing the toc using the titletoc package, hence would prefer a solution using that package rather than switching to something else.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss} 
\usepackage[pagestyles, outermarks]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{part}[0mm]  
  {\vspace{12pt}\large\normalfont\bfseries}  
  {\contentslabel{10mm}}{}            
  {\titlerule*[.75em]\bfseries{\contentspage}}  

\titlecontents{chapter}[9.3mm]     
  {\vspace{4pt}\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}  
  {\contentslabel{9.3mm}}{}   
  {\titlerule*[.75em]\bfseries{\contentspage}}  

\titlecontents{section}[21.6mm]   
  {\vspace{0pt}\normalsize\normalfont} 
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{12.3mm}}{}
  {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}{\contentspage}}   

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}   
\tableofcontents  
\clearpage

\chapter*{Preface}  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}  
\clearpage 

\pagenumbering{arabic}   
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand\thepart{I} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{I\arabic{chapter}}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{I\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{}
\clearpage 
\part{Island}               
\chapter{Desert}
\section{Shelter}
\chapter{Paradise}
\section{Beach}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand\thepart{W} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{W\arabic{chapter}}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{W\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}} 

\setcounter{page}{50}  
\clearpage
\part{Water}              
\chapter{Ice} 
\section{Snow}
\chapter{Liquid}
\section{Wave}

\clearpage 
\setcounter{page}{400} 
\renewcommand\thepart{L}  
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{L\arabic{chapter}}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{L\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}} 
\part{Land}             
\chapter{Continent}
\section{Mountain}
\chapter{Rock}  
\section{Stone}

\clearpage
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand\thepart{A} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{A\arabic{chapter}}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{A\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}} 
\part{Animals}               
\chapter{Mammals}
\section{Humans}
\chapter{Reptiles}
\section{Lizards}  

\end{document}
```

[image: minimal working example]

I have actually come upon a solution to problem 2 (page-number-non-alignment) just now at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330859)
Apparently \bfseries{\contentspage} influences the line filling in an unwanted way. The solution is to use \hfill\bfseries\thecontentspage, as in the revised code below, which produces nicely right-aligned page numbers, see below. I'm still stuck with problem 1, though.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss} 
\usepackage[pagestyles, outermarks]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{part}[0mm]  
  {\vspace{12pt}\large\normalfont\bfseries}  
  {\contentslabel{10mm}}{}            
  {\hfill\bfseries\thecontentspage}  

\titlecontents{chapter}[9.3mm]     
  {\vspace{4pt}\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}  
  {\contentslabel{9.3mm}}{}   
  {\hfill\bfseries\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{section}[21.6mm]   
  {\vspace{0pt}\normalsize\normalfont} 
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{12.3mm}}{}
  {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\thecontentspage}   

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}   
\tableofcontents  
\clearpage

\chapter*{Preface}  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}  
\clearpage 

\pagenumbering{arabic}   
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand\thepart{I} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{I\arabic{chapter}}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{I\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{}
\clearpage 
\part{Island}               
\chapter{Desert}
\section{Shelter}
\chapter{Paradise}
\section{Beach}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand\thepart{W} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{W\arabic{chapter}}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{W\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}} 

\setcounter{page}{50}  
\clearpage
\part{Water}              
\chapter{Ice} 
\section{Snow}
\chapter{Liquid}
\section{Wave}

\clearpage 
\setcounter{page}{400} 
\renewcommand\thepart{L}  
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{L\arabic{chapter}}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{L\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}} 
\part{Land}             
\chapter{Continent}
\section{Mountain}
\chapter{Rock}  
\section{Stone}

\clearpage
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand\thepart{A} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{A\arabic{chapter}}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{A\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}} 
\part{Animals}               
\chapter{Mammals}
\section{Humans}
\chapter{Reptiles}
\section{Lizards}  

\end{document}
```

[image: minimal working example]

Following up on the patch suggested by esdd to gain control of the label width for part, I post essd's version with two lines added to format the title of parts. These lines somehow interfere with the patch, because the title label is now shifted to the right.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss}
\usepackage[pagestyles, outermarks]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]%     this line messes up the patch
{\normalfont\Huge}{\centering\thepart}{1em}{\centering}                      
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large}{\thesection}{1em}{} 

\titlecontents{part}[10mm]
  {\vspace{12pt}\large\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel{10mm}}{}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{chapter}[10mm]
  {\vspace{4pt}\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel{10mm}}{}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{section}[22.3mm]
  {\vspace{0pt}\normalsize\normalfont}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{12.3mm}}{}
  {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\thecontentspage}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@part
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}% after the patch
```

[image: updated MWE]

Comment: From quick look at the code, it appears that package `titletoc` is intrinsically incapable of distinguishing a numbered part entry from an unnumbered part entry: it will always treat it as unnumbered and `\contentslabel` never does anything. At least in the `book` class. To avoid that you would need to hack into `\part` macro to modify what it adds to `.toc` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** (with redefinition of `\part` using `\titleformat`)

Regarding to the additions in the question: If you redefine `\part` using `\titleformat` patching `\@part` does not help anymore. But then adding the **option `newparttoc` for package `titlesec`** will solve your issue:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss}
\usepackage[pagestyles, outermarks,
  newparttoc% <- added
]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\Huge}{\centering\thepart}{1em}{\centering}%
  [\setcounter{chapter}{0}]% <- added to reset the chapter counter for each part

\contentsmargin{0pt}%<- added (as suggested by jvd in a comment)

\titlecontents{part}[10mm]% <- changed
  {\vspace{12pt}\large\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel{10mm}}{}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{chapter}[10mm]
  {\vspace{4pt}\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel{10mm}}{}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{section}[22.3mm]
  {\vspace{0pt}\normalsize\normalfont}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{12.3mm}}{}
  {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\thecontentspage}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\thepart\arabic{chapter}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\cleardoublepage 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand\thepart{I}
\part{Island}
\chapter{Desert}
\section{Shelter}
\chapter{Paradise}
\section{Beach}

\cleardoublepage% only for the example
\setcounter{page}{51}% only for the example
\renewcommand\thepart{W}
\part{Water}
\chapter{Ice}
\section{Snow}
\chapter{Liquid}
\section{Wave}

\cleardoublepage% only for the example
\setcounter{page}{401}% only for the example
\renewcommand\thepart{L}
\part{Land}
\chapter{Continent}
\section{Mountain}
\chapter{Rock}
\section{Stone}

\clearpage
\renewcommand\thepart{A}
\part{Animals}
\chapter{Mammals}
\section{Humans}
\chapter{Reptiles}
\section{Lizards}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Original answer** (without the redefinition of `\part` using `\titleformat`)

You could patch `\@part` to remove the fixed space between the part number and the entry text and to use `\numberline` instead.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@part
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss}
\usepackage[pagestyles, outermarks]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{part}[10mm]
  {\vspace{12pt}\large\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel{10mm}}{}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{chapter}[10mm]
  {\vspace{4pt}\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel{10mm}}{}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{section}[22.3mm]
  {\vspace{0pt}\normalsize\normalfont}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{12.3mm}}{}
  {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\thecontentspage}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@part
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}% after the patch

\xpretocmd\part{\setcounter{chapter}{0}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\thepart\arabic{chapter}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\cleardoublepage 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand\thepart{I}
\part{Island}
\chapter{Desert}
\section{Shelter}
\chapter{Paradise}
\section{Beach}

\cleardoublepage% only for the example
\setcounter{page}{51}% only for the example
\renewcommand\thepart{W}
\part{Water}
\chapter{Ice}
\section{Snow}
\chapter{Liquid}
\section{Wave}

\cleardoublepage% only for the example
\setcounter{page}{401}% only for the example
\renewcommand\thepart{L}
\part{Land}
\chapter{Continent}
\section{Mountain}
\chapter{Rock}
\section{Stone}

\clearpage
\renewcommand\thepart{A}
\part{Animals}
\chapter{Mammals}
\section{Humans}
\chapter{Reptiles}
\section{Lizards}
\end{document}
```

---

With KOMA-Script classes, there there is no need to patch an internal command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{scrbook} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss} 
%\usepackage[pagestyles, outermarks]{titlesec}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{part}[11mm]
  {\vspace{12pt}\large\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel{11mm}}{}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{chapter}[11mm]
  {\vspace{4pt}\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel{11mm}}{}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{section}[23.3mm]
  {\vspace{0pt}\normalsize\normalfont}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{12.3mm}}{}
  {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\thecontentspage}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
\xpretocmd\part{\setcounter{chapter}{0}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\thepart\arabic{chapter}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}

\clearpage 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand\thepart{I} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\thepart\arabic{chapter}}}
\part{Island}
\chapter{Desert}
\section{Shelter}
\chapter{Paradise}
\section{Beach}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{50}% only for the example
\renewcommand\thepart{W}
\part{Water}
\chapter{Ice} 
\section{Snow}
\chapter{Liquid}
\section{Wave}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{400}% only for the example
\renewcommand\thepart{L}
\part{Land}
\chapter{Continent}
\section{Mountain}
\chapter{Rock}
\section{Stone}

\clearpage
\renewcommand\thepart{A} 
\part{Animals}
\chapter{Mammals}
\section{Humans}
\chapter{Reptiles}
\section{Lizards}
\end{document}
```

But with KOMA-Script classes, there is also no need to use `tocloft` to format the toc entries:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{scrbook} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss} 
%\usepackage[pagestyles, outermarks]{titlesec}

\setuptoc{toc}{numberline}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  beforeskip=12pt,
  pagenumberbox=\pnmbox,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=10mm,
]{tocline}{part}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  beforeskip=4pt,
  pagenumberbox=\pnmbox,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=10mm,
]{tocline}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  indent=10mm,
  numwidth=12.3mm
]{tocline}{section}
\setkomafont{partentry}{\large\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcommand*\pnmbox[1]{\mbox{#1}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
\xpretocmd\part{\setcounter{chapter}{0}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\thepart\arabic{chapter}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}

\clearpage 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand\thepart{I} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\thepart\arabic{chapter}}}
\part{Island}
\chapter{Desert}
\section{Shelter}
\chapter{Paradise}
\section{Beach}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{50}% only for the example
\renewcommand\thepart{W}
\part{Water}
\chapter{Ice} 
\section{Snow}
\chapter{Liquid}
\section{Wave}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{400}% only for the example
\renewcommand\thepart{L}
\part{Land}
\chapter{Continent}
\section{Mountain}
\chapter{Rock}
\section{Stone}

\clearpage
\renewcommand\thepart{A} 
\part{Animals}
\chapter{Mammals}
\section{Humans}
\chapter{Reptiles}
\section{Lizards}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @esdd Thanks, your patch works great for the MWE. But in my actual code I also use \usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref} to get hyperlinks to page numbers in the toc. If I add that single line to your MWE, I get an error: Undefined control squence \PatchFailed. It would be great if you could make your patch compatible with hyperlink package. Thanks!

Comment: @jvd Load `hyperref` after the patch. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again, that works. But now I have a further problem. To keep my MWE 'minimal', I had left out two lines for formatting the titles generated by \part, namely \titleclass{\part}{top} \titleformat{\part}[display]{\normalfont\Huge}{\centering}{1em}{\centering}. When I add these, they kill the control over the label width that your patch so nicely provides; as a result the part label is shifted to the right to align with the chapter titles. I updated my question to show this issue. Would be fantastic if you could show me how to get over this final bump!

Comment: Then there is no patch needed. Simple use option `newparttoc` for `titlesec`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Fantastic, now its perfect, I marked your solution as accepted, thanks a ton! Final remark: to get a toc whose width perfectly matches the pagewidth, I had to add \contentsmargin{0mm} to your code (without it, the toc was narrower than the pagewidth by about 10mm). Maybe you could add that line to your code, for the benefit of future readers?