TOC Inconsistent and erratic spacing
I'm facing some inconsistencies in the distance between the Counter and the Title in TOC.
MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fmtcount} % For ordinal numbers

% Page layout
\geometry{a4paper, left=30mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=30mm}

% Adjust font sizes and styles in the table of contents
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\normalsize} % Bold and font size
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\bfseries\normalsize} % Page numbers in bold
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{28mm} % Space for counter

\renewcommand{\thepart}{%
  \Ordinalstring{part} Teil:}

\newcommand{\mainpart}[1]{%
  \part{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

% Test entries
\mainpart{HA very very very very very very long title for a part Hthat gets wrapped}
 \setcounter{part}{0}
\mainpart{HA not so much shorter title for a loooo oooooong part Hthat is wrapped differently.}
 \setcounter{part}{0}
\mainpart{HAnother long title, which unfortunately is also not Hcorrectly formatted.}

\end{document}

Output:

As you can see the H in the second row are all perfectly aligned, while the ones in the first rows are not.
Also happens in english.
I tried to add dynamic spacing, but could not make it work. Another try was with boxes but they mess with the position of the page numbers.

The code in this answer worked for me
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394667/alignment-problems-for-part-and-chapter-in-table-of-contents-created-with-titl?rq=1
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd@part
{\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
{\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}}
{}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother



You are setting the entire entry as a paragraph so the part number is taking part in the justificaton and so the Erster Teil parts stretch to different lengths. I added an \mbox to fix them at their natural size
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fmtcount} % For ordinal numbers

% Page layout
\geometry{a4paper, left=30mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=30mm}

% Adjust font sizes and styles in the table of contents
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\normalsize} % Bold and font size
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\bfseries\normalsize} % Page numbers in bold
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{28mm} % Space for counter

\renewcommand{\thepart}{%
  \mbox{\Ordinalstring{part} Teil:}}

\newcommand{\mainpart}[1]{%
  \part{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

% Test entries
\mainpart{HA very very very very very very long title for a part Hthat gets wrapped}
 \setcounter{part}{0}
\mainpart{HA not so much shorter title for a loooo oooooong part Hthat is wrapped differently.}
 \setcounter{part}{0}
\mainpart{HAnother long title, which unfortunately is also not Hcorrectly formatted.}

\end{document}


Thank you. Could you specify where exactly you put the \mbox?

@Jannis oh sorry, I forgot to add the code :-) give me a second...

@Jannis try now:-)

Thank you, unfortunately it doesn't work if the part counter counts up.

It seems that patching @part as mentioned here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394667/alignment-problems-for-part-and-chapter-in-table-of-contents-created-with-titl?rq=1 will solve the problem
